# It is better to return a list from a function, overwriting a list variable, than modify a list within the function

Tags: python

I understand mutable and immutable concepts in Python. However, I find it confusing sometimes to handle them in some situation. Let's illustrate some examples here. I also printed out `id` of these Python objects:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3]
c = [1,2,3]

def fun(param_a, param_b, param_c):
    print(f'  id(param_a)={id(param_a)}  param_a = {param_a}')
    print(f'  id(param_b)={id(param_b)}  param_b = {param_b}')
    print(f'  id(param_c)={id(param_c)}  param_c = {param_c}')

    param_a.append(999)  # It will change a
    local_a = param_a    # Make a local alias to param_a
    local_a.append(12345)
    param_b = [3,3,3]    # Python creates a new object
    param_c.clear()      # Python will change c
    param_c.append(999)

    print(f'  id(param_a)={id(param_a)}  param_a = {param_a}')
    print(f'  id(param_b)={id(param_b)}  param_b = {param_b}')
    print(f'  id(param_c)={id(param_c)}  param_c = {param_c}')

print(f'id(a)={id(a)}  a = {a}')
print(f'id(b)={id(b)}  a = {b}')
print(f'id(c)={id(c)}  a = {c}')
print('Calling func(a,b,c)')
fun(a, b, c)
print('Return from func(a,b,c)')
print(f'id(a)={id(a)}  a = {a}')
print(f'id(b)={id(b)}  a = {b}')
print(f'id(c)={id(c)}  a = {c}')
```

The outputs:

```
id(a)=2552952620744  a = [1, 2, 3]
id(b)=2552952582536  a = [1, 2, 3]
id(c)=2552952620424  a = [1, 2, 3]
Calling func(a,b,c)
  id(param_a)=2552952620744  param_a = [1, 2, 3]
  id(param_b)=2552952582536  param_b = [1, 2, 3]
  id(param_c)=2552952620424  param_c = [1, 2, 3]
  id(param_a)=2552952620744  param_a = [1, 2, 3, 999, 12345]
  id(param_b)=2552952619272  param_b = [3, 3, 3]
  id(param_c)=2552952620424  param_c = [999]
Return from func(a,b,c)
id(a)=2552952620744  a = [1, 2, 3, 999, 12345]
id(b)=2552952582536  a = [1, 2, 3]
id(c)=2552952620424  a = [999]
```

A simpler approach is to return the lists, overwriting global lists. The only issue is performance and memory requirements.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3]
c = [1,2,3]

def fun(param_a, param_b, param_c):
    print(f'  id(param_a)={id(param_a)}  param_a = {param_a}')
    print(f'  id(param_b)={id(param_b)}  param_b = {param_b}')
    print(f'  id(param_c)={id(param_c)}  param_c = {param_c}')

    param_a.append(999)  # It will change a
    local_a = param_a    # Make a local alias to param_a
    local_a.append(12345)
    param_b = [3,3,3]    # Python creates a new object
    param_c = [999]      # Python creates a new object

    print(f'  id(param_a)={id(param_a)}  param_a = {param_a}')
    print(f'  id(param_b)={id(param_b)}  param_b = {param_b}')
    print(f'  id(param_c)={id(param_c)}  param_c = {param_c}')
    return param_a, param_b, param_c

print(f'id(a)={id(a)}  a = {a}')
print(f'id(b)={id(b)}  a = {b}')
print(f'id(c)={id(c)}  a = {c}')
print('Calling func(a,b,c)')
a, b, c = fun(a, b, c)
print('Return from func(a,b,c)')
print(f'id(a)={id(a)}  a = {a}')
print(f'id(b)={id(b)}  a = {b}')
print(f'id(c)={id(c)}  a = {c}')
```

The outputs:

```
id(a)=2552952621192  a = [1, 2, 3]
id(b)=2552952619464  a = [1, 2, 3]
id(c)=2552952620744  a = [1, 2, 3]
Calling func(a,b,c)
  id(param_a)=2552952621192  param_a = [1, 2, 3]
  id(param_b)=2552952619464  param_b = [1, 2, 3]
  id(param_c)=2552952620744  param_c = [1, 2, 3]
  id(param_a)=2552952621192  param_a = [1, 2, 3, 999, 12345]
  id(param_b)=2552952620424  param_b = [3, 3, 3]
  id(param_c)=2552952621256  param_c = [999]
Return from func(a,b,c)
id(a)=2552952621192  a = [1, 2, 3, 999, 12345]
id(b)=2552952620424  a = [3, 3, 3]
id(c)=2552952621256  a = [999]
```

I also could not use `copy.deepcopy()` to passed parameters to function.

Is there a better approach to modify passed parameters (which may not be simple lists, sets or dictionary)?

Comment: You may also take a look at `global` and `nonlocal` keywords.

Comment: There's no single answer to this question. The best approach depends on what you need to do in the application.

Comment: The pyrsistent library is probably the best of both worlds. Its vectors are immutable, but modifications don't double the memory requried like a full copy would.